# CAPTCHA creation

Tags: .net, asp.net, captcha

How can one create a captcha application as a field in the form say registration form...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get from here http://www.captcha.net/

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

go to recaptcha website,register your website there ,they will give dll ,add that reference to your project and include that wherever you want in your web form.

something like this(i am not sure of this code..),

```
<recaptcha:control runat='server'.....>
..
</recpatcha>
```